# Should SE twitter accounts retweet when possible?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, twitter

When a subject is popular enough, I always see it a certain number or times. (Most being due to me following many SE people now.)

This let me think of a possible improvement for our twitter bot. 
The generic account (who is twitting multiple sites questions) could use the specific sites accounts and **retweet** it instead of making a new tweet.

Two advantages on this:

- Followers of the two account see it once
- Followers of the general accounts becomes aware of the child accounts.

Is it possible? What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now completed on the main central network account:

http://twitter.com/StackExchange

We may experiment with other forms of RT on the site accounts as well, eventually.

Comment: Great! Thank you. This will make my timeline a lot easier to read!

Answer (score 4):

I would like it if the individual accounts could monitor links to their sites (this might involve understanding shortened links; if nothing else it could spot the shortener used by the actual tweet button on the site) and RT whenever a person happens to tweet a link. In this way, a person who is following a site account becomes exposed to humans who are tweeting on the same subject matter, and gains new people to follow - this makes the site accounts more valuable to follow. As well, the person who got RTed will become aware of the site account if they weren't already. And so on.

There's a saying: RT is the Like button of Twitter. If the site accounts RT, people will feel liked.

Comment: We are still looking at this, I am in favor of it but it's tricky. Also see my other answer.