# Should moderators be allowed to retweet from the @Stack Twitter accounts?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, twitter

We've talked about ways of improving the Twitter accounts before:

- [Would allowing moderators to update their Stack Exchange sites' Twitter accounts improve visibility and offer more value?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/100964#comment-261754)
- [Should SE twitter accounts retweet when possible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101847/should-se-twitter-accounts-retweet-when-possible)

Jeff made a good point in one of the [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/100964#100964):

> Part of the reason Twitter is interesting is because the accounts are
>   actual people, not generic services or companies.

Even if we got the algorithm perfect, and only the *best of the best* questions were highlighted, it's never going to feel like a real person.

Even if we had real people moderating the accounts, the same tweets are less interesting when they come from a corporate account instead of an individual.

In order to make the Twitter accounts both useful and *personal*, I think we should **allow the moderators to retweet community members** when they say something interesting about the site or the subject matter.

Should that be done, at least on a trial basis? For example, give each moderator up to 2 RTs a week, in addition to the stream of tweets that are automatically generated?

Answer (score 7):

We have plans for the twitter accounts to automatically search twitter and periodically retweet (after some vetting) any tweets by other users that

- mention that Stack Exchange site
- link to a question on that Stack Exchange site

Comment: I'm curious why your answers re: moderators tweeting always sidestep the issue of *actually allowing people to tweet things*. Have you guys just decided that you don't want to "trust" (for lack of a better word) people with these accounts, or do you believe in the power of algorithmic tweets over the judgement of people, or... what is it? I accept you want to do things a certain way but I want to understand why.

Comment: @rahul we have 65+ sites -- we prioritize changes that benefit *all* sites not just the ones where someone is willing to manually intervene

Comment: @JeffAtwood I've thought about this, and I think if you give people the tools to manually intervene, they will take advantage of them. That should be evident in the amount of interest that was generated by [Rahul's original question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/100964#comment-261754).